Proving an equivalent form of the essential spectrum for a self adjoint densely operator.
Let $T$ be a self adjoint densely defined operator on a Hilbert space. I am trying to show that a real number $\lambda$ will be in the essential spectrum iff there exists an orthonormal sequence $e_n$ so that $\|(T - \lambda)e_n\|$ converges to $0$. I have proven that $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $T$ iff there exists a sequence $\|e_n\| = 1$ so that $\|(T - \lambda) e_n\|$ converges to $0$.
For the forward direction if $\ker(T - \lambda )$ is infinite dimensional, then it is easy to construct an orthonormal sequence that has the property we want. I am having trouble when $\ker(T - \lambda)$ is finite dimensional case. I was trying to prove it when $T - \lambda$ is injective. I was trying to make an argument by constructing a subsequence that $\forall n \exists m > n \langle e_n, e_m \rangle = 0$ since we would know that $\|(T - \lambda)e_n\| > 0$ but I don't think this works.
For the reverse, we have to consider we just have to consider when the kernel is finite dimensional and I was trying to prove that $\lambda$ cannot be an isolated point.

I know it's not the main focus of the question, but remember that elements of the spectrum need not be eigenvalues because injectivity and surjectivity are not equivalent in the infinite-dimensional world, so that $\ker T - \lambda I$ could be zero.

There are several equivalent definitions for essential spectrum. Which one are you using? And are you familiar with Weyl's criterion?
